# Magento 2: How to get all order status

Tags: magento-2.1, order-status

I am using magento version 2.1.How to get all order status options in my custom module?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got solution code as below:

```
    /**
     * @var Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Status\CollectionFactory $statusCollectionFactory
     */
    protected $statusCollectionFactory;


    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Status\CollectionFactory $statusCollectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(Template\Context $context,
            \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Status\CollectionFactory $statusCollectionFactory
        ) 
    {       
        $this->statusCollectionFactory = $statusCollectionFactory;      
        parent::__construct($context);
    }



    /**
     * Get status options
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getStatusOptions()
    {       
        $options = $this->statusCollectionFactory->create()->toOptionArray();        
        return $options;
    }
```

Comment: could you please add the code with complete full path, Why because, some users cant able to know the path to use this code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get just order statuses. Use the following class.

```
<?php
namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Model;

class MyClass
{
    protected $orderStatus;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Config\Source\Order\Status $orderStatus
    ){
        $this->orderStatus = $orderStatus;
    }

    public function getOrderStatuses()
    {
        return $this->orderStatus->toOptionArray();
    }
}
```

In case you have a drop down field in system configuration, you can directly use the aforementioned class in source_model as follows.

```
<field id="status" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Order Status</label>
    <source_model>Magento\Sales\Model\Config\Source\Order\Status</source_model>
</field>
```

In case you need order statuses along with the respective states, use the following way.

```
<?php
namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Model;

class MyClass
{
    protected $orderStatus;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Status $orderStatus
    ){
        $this->orderStatus = $orderStatus;
    }

    public function getOrderStatuses()
    {
        $orderStatuses = $this->orderStatus->getCollection();
        $orderStatuses->joinStates();
        return $orderStatuses;
    }
}
```